# Accessing JSON object value using components input parameter

Tags: angular

I am new with angular and I am having problems understanding why I cannot access JSON object values using component input parameter as a key.

In my app component I have three components added:

```
<app-example input="example1"></app-example>
<app-example input="example2"></app-example>
<app-example input="example3"></app-example>
```

Component "app-example" imports config JSON file as config and has @Input() input: string;

Inside "app-example" component I am trying to access config in ngOnInit() using config[this.input]

When I console.log(config[this.input]) it prints out undefined
When I console.log(this.input) it prints out the input string (for example "example1")
however if I for example console.log(config["example1"]) it prints out the corresponding object.

This is probably something very basic but I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: Wild guess, since you didn't post the code. You need `this.input`, not `input`. The compiler should warn you about this error.

Comment: That was typo from my end. I did actually use this.input.  I just found out that if I import like this: import config from "/config.json" instead of import * as config from "/config.json" it seems to work. Would be nice to know why

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for using Angular inputs is: `@Input() input: string` (note, that you are missing the parenthesis in your example).

Here is the simple example that works:

**app.component.html**

`<app-foo bar="baz"></app-foo>`

**bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.scss']
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() bar: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Shows undefined:', this.bar);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Shows baz:', this.bar);
  }
}
```

If you run this, it will show `baz` in the console.

You can read more about Input: https://angular.io/api/core/Input.

Comment: Hi! You´re right about the syntax of @Input(), I did cut corners when I was writing my question. I have used the correct syntax in my actual code. The problem was the JSON import which needed to be  import config from "/config.json" instead of import * as config from "/config.json"   I wonder what is the difference with these?